# Simple Flash Input Validation

Tags: forms, flash, validation, input, actionscript-2

I have a flash Ad with two simple inputs, Name and Telephone.

When pressed submit it simply post the form via php to an email address which works.

I want the submit button to be stay disabled until valid input is placed in the fields.

Comment: Is your language actionScript 3 or actionScript 2?

Comment: Its AS2

This is the code that I have right now onrelase to the submit button

on (release) {
  form.loadVariables("http://getparfume.ru/test.php", "POST");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enabled` property, a `Boolean` value that indicates whether a movie clip is enabled:

**Timeline code**

```
myButton.enabled = false;
```

On `change` in your two inputs:

```
if (/*conditions to validate my inputs*/) {
   myButton.enabled = true;
}
```

**Button code**

```
on (release) {
   form.loadVariables("getparfume.ru/test.php", "POST");
}
```

Comment: it does not change anything.

It is still enabled and also posts the form even with empty fields.

Comment: @user2493253 - If your movie clip isn't a button, you must use focusEnabled: `this.focusEnabled = false;`

Comment: still does not work, here is the link of fla file.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3tbJ_7dd8OreFd4MHR5Z19iVFU&usp=sharing

I can understand the code recommended to add is to enable or disable the button but where is the condition to validate the form first?

Comment: @user2493253 - I thought that your question was about `enabled` property. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main useful tools:

- textfield.restrict by restricting specific characters - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8d7bb3e8da6fb92f-20050207122bd5f80cb-7ff6.html
- add an event listener to the input textfield (flash.events.Event.CHANGE) - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:change

Answer (score 0):

user2493253

on clicking the submit button you have to validate the textfield whether it has the string values for names or numbers on telephone textfield.

for eg.

_submitButton.onRelease = function()  {

//   I just wrote for demo condition here you can validate as you need for your condition.

if(nameTextField.text != "" && telephoneTextField.text != "" )
   form.loadVariables("getparfume.ru/test.php";, "POST"); }

}